# Is it possible to limit an external process CPU usage?

Tags: windows-xp, limit, cpu-usage

Because i cannot find such a program that lets me control how many percent i will allow a process to use my CPU core... is this even possible?

Edit: Sorry i forgot to mention im using windows-xp

Comment: Any particular operating system? I suspect this capability will be entirely dependent upon your OS of choice.

Comment: Ah, sorry i forgot to mention. Fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically limit CPU usage by any application on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777137/programmatically-limit-cpu-usage-by-any-application-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

[TThrottle](http://www.efmer.eu/boinc/) does that. I don't know exactly how I must confess.