# Separating a Client and Server into different cores in a batch script

Tags: java, batch-file, client, minecraft

I'm trying to find a way to make two processes; `java` and `javaw` separate over a set of cores (0-1 and 6-7) to make the programme I'm running go faster as I am using a client and server and both will only use a maximum of two cores, no more each. I can do this manually, but would like to find a less time taking method of getting it done.

Comment: Create two threads in each and let the operating system schedule them?  If you need finer grained control, investigate how to tell your operating system what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Windows. What you want to do is set the processor affinity mask.

If you want to run a process on core 0 and 1 start the application using

```
start /AFFINITY 03 <program>
```

which uses the bitmask 0x03 (00000011 in binary).

If you want to run a process on core 6 and 7 start the application using

```
start /AFFFINITY CO <program>
```

which uses the bitmask 0xCO (11000000 in binary).

Also check [Set affinity with start /AFFINITY command on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759948/set-affinity-with-start-affinity-command-on-windows-7)