# DOS Batch multicore affinity not working

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, dos, affinity

I have a batch that launches a few executables .exe and .py (python) to process some data.

With **start /affinity X mybatch.bat** 
it will work as it should only if X equals to 0, 2, 4 or 8 (the individual cores)
But if I will use a multicore X like 15 or F or 0xF (meaning in my opinion all 4 cores) it will still run only on the first core.

Does it have to do with the fact that the batch is calling .exe files that maybe cannot be affinity controled this way?

OS:Windows 7 64bit

Comment: How do you check which CPU your program is running on?

Comment: Affinity is a mask of allowable cores/cpus. It doesn't magically make single-threaded programs multi-threaded. Sure you can run those .exe pinned to core each at the same time, but OS scheduler sort of does that by default, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an answer to a question that arose in comments, but I hope it might help.  I have to add it as an answer only because it grew too large for the comment limits:

There seems to be a misconception about two things here: what "processor affinity" actually means, and how the Windows scheduler actually works.

What this `SetProcessAffinityMask(...)` means is "which *processors* can this *process* (i.e. "*all* threads *within* the process") can run on,"

whereas

`SetThreadAffinityMask(...)` is distinctly thread-specific.

The Windows scheduler (at the most base level) makes absolutely no distinction between threads and processes - a "process" is simply a container that contains one or more threads.  IOW (and over-simplified) - there is no such thing as a *process* to the scheduler, "threads" are schedulable things: *processes* have *nothing* to do with this ("processes" are more life-cycle-management issues about open handles, resources, etc.)

If you have a single-threaded process, it does not matter much what you set the "process" affinity mask to: that *one* thread will be scheduled by the scheduler (for whatever masked processors) according to 1) which processor it was last bound to - ideal case, less overhead, 2) whichever processor is next available for a given *runnable* thread of the same priority (more complicated than this, but the general idea), and 3) *possibly transient*  issues about priority inversion, waitable objects, kernel APC events, etc.

So to answer your question (much more long-windedly than expected):

> "But if I will use a multicore X like 15 or F or 0xF (meaning in my opinion all 4 cores) it will still run only on the first core"

What I said earlier about the scheduler attempting to use the most-recently-used processor is important here: if you have a (or an essentially) single-threaded process, the scheduling algorithm goes for the most-optimistic approach: previously-bound CPU for the switchback (likely cheaper for CPU/main memory cache, prior branch-prediction eval, etc).  This explains why you'll see an app (regardless of process-level affinity) with only one (again, caveats apply here) thread seemingly "stuck" to one CPU/core.

So:

What you are effectively doing with the "/affinity X" switch is

1) constraining the scheduler to *only* schedule your threads on a subset of CPU cores (i.e. *not all*), and
2) limit them to a subset of what the scheduler kernel considers "available for next runnable thread switch-to", and
3) if they are not multithreaded apps (and capable of taking advantage of that), "more cores" does not really help anything - you might just be bouncing that single thread of execution around to different cores (although the scheduler tries to minimize this, as described above).

That is why your threads are "sticky" - you are telling the scheduler to make them so.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK /AFFINITY uses a hex values as parameter. Here's more information on this topic: [Set affinity with start /AFFINITY command on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759948/set-affinity-with-start-affinity-command-on-windows-7)

EDIT: `0xF` should be the correct parameter for you as you want to load all 4 CPUs which requires the bit-mask `00001111` which is `F` in **hex**.

Comment: I believe you have answered this question just for taking points for being the first answer. I have asked another question.

Comment: I belive that you are not willing to think about the answer.

Comment: what would be a hex value for all cores in a quad-core processor? I have tried the F and the 0xF parameter

Comment: 0xFF means 11111111 means all 8 CPUs are loaded.

Comment: Just tried the command `start /affinity 0xF notepad`, then checked via the task manager and notepad is running on CPUs 0, 1, 2, 3. So 0xF should work.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant. It says Which processors are allowed to run "cmd.exe" in the affinity properties. All of the cores are checked as expected. But if I will look at batch1.exe, the process launched by mybatch.bat, it will still run only on the first core using it 100% and the rest idle, so total processor usage is 25%. Even if I assign it manually from task manager to all the cores.

Comment: Please tell me that you don't think that running a programm as multicore makes it automatically BE multicore. If your code is not written using multithreadding techniques it will always use only one thread. Running a program on more than one CPU will only ALLOW the program to use more than one core. But you still have to implement it in the correct way. It won't just work in parallel itself!