# Android Studio Build uses 100% CPU on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, build, windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 10 building a project in Android Studio makes the
PC unusable.
With Windows 10 the build did also take a long time, but the PC
was useable in the meantime.

The TaskManager shows that the java-build-task uses as much CPU as it can get.

Setting java and or gradle-options did not improve the CPU usage.

**Currently using:**
Android Studio 2.1.0
Gradle 2.1.0
Windows 10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating a new shortcut which launches Android Studio with restricted CPU affinity did the trick for me.

1. Desktop > right click > New > Shortcut
2. Set location to 
   `cmd.exe /c start "Android Studio" /affinity 0x03 "C:\Path\to\ANDROID_STUDIO"`
3. Set desired name of shortcut
4. set Icon to `C:\path\to\Android Studio\bin\studio.ico`

The number for affinity are the hexadecimal encoded numbers of the cores to use.

```
Core4 Core3 Core2 Core1 = 0x0F //uses all cores 
            Core2 Core1 = 0x03 //uses only first 2 cores
```

I experienced no noticeable worsening in build times.

Comment: My configuration to use first 6 cores:

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start "AndroidStudio" /affinity 3F "C:\AndroidStudio\bin\studio64.exe"

Comment: 0x03 = 3 in decimal bro not 2

Comment: Actually the number is the binary mask, for example 0xAA (10101010) requests that your process run using processors 1, 3, 5 and 7, but not 0, 2, 4 or 6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/7760105/2093236